# Spark read subgroup of binary files

Tags: python, regex, binary, apache-spark, pyspark

Is there a simple way to read only a given set of files contained in a directory with a Spark API (I use PySpark API) and the binaryFiles method?

Let's say I have a folder like this:

```
/temp
  a.bin
  b.bin
  ...
  y.bin
  z.bin
```

And I want to read g.bin, j.bin, d.bin, z.bin, l.bin, a.bin, i.bin, h.bin (these are random names and could change at each request).

How can I read those files using binaryFiles without copying them in another directory since they are large files?

For now, I am creating a folder with symbolic links and I use binaryFiles('./*') to read all the links in the folder. But I don't think it is viable for long-term use.

Some tips: I am investigating regexp so I can pass to binaryFiles a custom string to select the proper files but the solution may be elsewhere and help is more than welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With single letter prefix you can simply use [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) pattern:

```
sc.binaryFiles('[gjdzlaih].bin')
```

If names are more complex it could be easier to provide comma separated list of files:

```
files = ['g.bin', 'j.bin', 'd.bin', 'z.bin', 'l.bin', 'a.bin', 'i.bin', 'h.bin']
sc.binaryFiles(','.join(files))
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Using glob pattern does the job for me.
The second syntax doesn't seem to work for me but using glob pattern like:
    filenames = ['g', 'j', 'd','z']
    sc.binaryFiles('temp/*{' + ','.join(filenames) + '}.bin')

Comment: That's strange. I've tested simple comma separated list and it worked just fine. As far as I know all basic read commands in Spark should accept this format.